# Separating a substring from a string

Tags: c++

I have the following string:

```
std::string str = "Mode:AAA:val:101:id:A1";
```

I would like to separate a substring which is placed between `"val:"` and `":id"` Here is my approach:

```
std::string pattern1 = "val:";
std::string pattern2 = ":id";
auto pattern1begin = str.find(pattern1);
auto pattern2begin = str.find(pattern2);
auto pattern1end = pattern1begin + pattern1.size();
auto substrlength = pattern2begin - pattern1end;
auto val = str.substr(pattern1end, substrlength);
```

Do you know some other methods which can be used to separate substring in the above case (including boost or std::regex) ?

Comment: Will you always have the number you need between `:val:` and `:id:`? Maybe you could look at a regex!

Comment: Either use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to separate on `':'`. Or possible use [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

Comment: You should start second find with offset and not from the start

Comment: This uses just 2 string searches and elementary iterator arithmetics. Unsure you can find anything faster... Except that you could try to find pattern2 after pattern1end to avoid searching in non appropriate places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to find `val:XXX` and get `XXX` instead of what is between `val:` and `:id`

If XXX is a sequence of numbers, then you can do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Mode:id:AAA:val:101:id:A1";
    std::smatch matches;
    if (std::regex_search(str, matches, std::regex("val:(\\d+)")))
    {
        std::cout <<  matches[1];
    }
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/zFQnDw